# If $A$ is a norm-preserving linear map (+ other conditions), then it is an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm studying "Semi-Riemannian Geometry: The Mathematical Language of General Relativity" by Stephen Newman. Theorem 4.4.4 in that book:

> Let $(V,g)$ be a scalar product space, and let $A:V\to V$ be a linear map. Then:
>
> 1. If $A$ is a linear isometry, then $\|A(v)\|=\|v\|\ \forall\ v\in V$
> 2. If $\|A(v)\|=\|v\|\ \forall\ v\in V$, and if $A$ maps spacelike (resp. timelike and lightlike) vectors to spacelike (resp. timelike and lightlike) , then $A$ is a linear isometry.

The proof of part 2 is given like this:

> Since $\|A(v)\|=\|v\|$ is equivalent to $|\langle A(v),A(v)\rangle|=|\langle v,v\rangle|$, the assumption regarding the way $A$ maps vectors yields $\langle A(v),A(v)\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle$.

I'm guessing the proof is incomplete? In that case, I'd like to know if my approach is correct:

$$\langle A(v+tw),A(v+tw)\rangle=\langle A(v)+tA(w),A(v)+tA(w)\rangle
\\
=\langle A(v),A(v)\rangle+t^2\langle A(w),A(w)\rangle+2t\langle A(v),A(w)\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle+t^2\langle w,w\rangle+2t\langle A(v),A(w)\rangle$$

But $$\langle A(v+tw),A(v+tw)\rangle=\langle v+tw,v+tw\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle+t^2\langle w,w\rangle+2t\langle v,w\rangle$$

(I'm not even sure if the $t$ coefficient matters) The above shows that $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle A(v),A(w)\rangle$.

Is this fine? Secondly, wouldn't this same theorem more generally hold for a linear map $A:V\to W$, where $V,W$ are both scalar product spaces?

Comment: You can as well apply the polar identity  $\langle v,w\rangle ={1\over 4}[\|v+w\|^2-\|v-w\|^2].$ A similar formula but with four summands is valid for the complex valued inner product.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Thanks for that! I'd forgotten about the identity. But does the theorem hold in the more general case that I specified at the end? (you can post the response as an answer if you like, so that I can accept)

Comment: Yes, the property $W=V$ does not produce any difference as the identity holds in both spaces  relating their inner products with their norms. Moreover your proof covers the more general case.